# VB6.0 and IBM DB2: Search data in database

Tags: database, search, vb6, db2

I'm using ibmDB2 and VB6.0, trying to retrieve data from database and display it in a combo box for my search function. The Table name is Supplier, the column that I want to display in the combo box is Supp_CompanyName.

But then after I've done the coding, I face an "Expected: End of Statement" error in the do loop under Private Sub Form section. 
Any idea on how to fix this error?

### Thanks :)

Below are my codes for the View Supplier Information Form:

```
Private Sub Combo1_Change()
Adodc1.RecordSource = "select * from Supplier where Supp_CompanyName='" & Combo1 & "'"
Adodc1.Refresh

End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Adodc1.RecordSource = "Select * from Supplier "
Adodc1.Refresh

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Adodc1.ConnectionString = "Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Data Source=ToyStore"
Combo1.Clear
Adodc1.RecordSource = "Select distinct Supp_CompanyName from Supplier"
Adodc1.Refresh

With Adodc1.Recordset 
Do Until .EOF 
    Combo1.AddItem ![Supp_CompanyName] 
    .MoveNext
Loop
End With

Adodc1.RecordSource = "Supplier"
Adodc1.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: This may just be your misunderstanding of SO's formatting and nothing to do with your actual problem, but there should be carriage returns before the `Do`, `Combo1` and `.MoveNext`. There should also be no gap between `Combo1` and `.Additem`.

Comment: I don't understand what is carriage returns, mind explaining it? 
And do you mean by Combo1.AddItem![Supp_CompanyName]?
Thanks!

Comment: In the code sample above, the line beginning the `With` block contains 4 lines of code that should be on separate lines. The gap between `.AddItem` and the field (`![Supp_CompanyName]`) is correct, but the gap before `.Additem` is not.

Comment: Now there's no error in the code already, but then when I run it, vb crash. Do you know why? T.T

Comment: On which line is the crash occurring? If you're not sure, put a breakpoint in the procedure (place the cursor at the top and press F9) then, when you run into the procedure it will stop in debug mode so you can step through the code one line at a time (by pressing F8) until you identify which line causes the problem.

Comment: It doesn't clash anymore, but then now there's an error from the Microsoft DataGrid Control saying that "DB2ADMIN.Supplier" is an undefined name. SQLSTATE = 42704.
Does it has anything to do with my "Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Data Source=ToyStore"?

Comment: It's probably a setting of the ADO data control or DataGrid you've got wrong somewhere, but I'm not really familiar with using databound controls, preferring instead the greater management provided by unbound methods. Maybe you can learn something [from here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0206hasin/0206hasin.html). Also, your problem now bears no relationship at all to the original post, so it would probably be better if you delete this post and create a new one that details the new problem and when/how it is occurring.

Comment: Alright, noted that, thanks! :)